# Problems with XMLHttpRequest and PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm fairly new to both JavaScript and PHP, so I hope this problem isn't as complex as it seems to me. I'm trying to send data from a form to a PHP file using XMLHttpRequest, and then display the output of the PHP as an alert.  Here's the HTML and JavaScript:

```
<form onSubmit="password_Check()"> 
        <input type="password" size="40" name="password" id="pass"> 
        <input type="submit" value="Go">
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
function password_Check() {
    var url = "test.php";
    var pass = $("#pass").val();
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("GET", url+"?pass="+pass, true);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
        alert(xhr.responseText);
        }
    }
}   
</script>
```

And here's the PHP:

```
<?php
    $pass = $_GET["pass"];
    echo "The password is $pass!  We've done it!";
?>
```

I've tried all sorts of ways to do this, like $.post, $.get, $.ajax, and an xhr using POST.  But I can't seem to get this to work.  Now it just appends "?password=(whatever I put)" onto the end of the current url, which does nothing, but it shows it's doing something.

Comment: You forgot to send the request: `xhr.send(null);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code you are missing the `send` part where you actually trigger the request. If you are not triggering the request then there is no point of the event listeners which listen for the state changes.

do it like

```
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if(xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
    alert(xhr.responseText);
    }
}
xhr.send();
```

Also in your question you are mentioning about jquery ajax, with `$.get` your code could be as simple as

```
$("#form1").on("submit",function(e){

    e.preventDefault();
    var url = "test.php?pass=" + $("#pass").val(); 
    $.get(url,function(data){
       //handle data here
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to execute the request. `xhr.send()`:

Also note that since you're having an XMLHTTPRequest, you need to prevent the default behavior (which is the form is going to be submitted) by using `.preventDefault();`

```
<form id="form1"> 
        <input type="password" size="40" name="password" id="pass"> 
        <input type="submit" value="Go">
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
// handle the submission event
document.getElementById('form1').addEventListener('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); // prevent from submitting
    var url = "test.php";
    var pass = document.getElementById('pass').value; // be faithful!, just use plain javascript

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var params = '?pass='+pass;
    xhr.open("GET", url+params, true);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
        alert(xhr.responseText);
        }
    }
    xhr.send(); // send it
});
</script>
```

Comment: You should point out that you are also preventing the default behavior in your submit handling function, the OP not doing this is what is causing the http redirect.

Comment: Of course it would be something simple!  Thank you!

Comment: @Ghost I may have spoken too soon, sadly.  I studied your code and wrote it out, and then gave up and copy-pasted it, but I still have the exact same problem.  I've narrowed down the problem to the fact that the code simply never executes.  I put the id in form1, but it's not doing anything.

Comment: Nevermind, @Ghost.  I replaced the firs line with this: `$(document).on('submit', "#form1", function(e){` Now it works!

Comment: @ASimpleMan i just answered this just to continue what you have on your initial post of codes, if the jquery variant worked, glad it wen't your way, anyway i also upvoted the second answer since that one seems to fit on your revision

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery then better use jQuery's ajax functions instead of xhr by yourself!

Also if you are submitting the password, better not submit it using GET request as it will be visible in the URL. Instead always use POST when handling Passwords!

Client side:

```
<form action="/index.php" id="myform" method="post">
        <input type="password" size="40" name="password" id="pass"> 
        <input type="submit" value="Go">
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $('#myform').on('submit', function() {
      $.ajax({
        type: $(this).attr('method'), //Taking for the form attribute
        url: $(this).attr('action'),
        data: $(this).serialize(), //Takes care of all input fields in the form! No need to pass one by one!
        success: function(response) {
          if(response == 'success') {
            window.location.href = '/url-to-goto';  //Set your redirect url here
          }
          else {
            //Handle invalid password here
            alert(response);
          }
        }
      });

      return false;
  });
</script>
```

Server side:

```
<?php

//If you are handling password, better to put it in the post body instead of url for security reasons
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
  //Check password here
  if(isset($_POST['password']) && $_POST['password'] == '123') {
    die('success'); //successful! redirect user!
  }

  die('Invalid password!');
}
?>
```

Hope that helps you better understand!